# How to form JSON in Java with multi rows in the lower level

Tags: java, json

I'm new in Java and JSON and I'm trying to form JSON for my rest api (I previously used XML and converter cause I'm using AngularJS, but I would like to form JSON without conversioning).
The format of the JSON should be:

```
{
  "friends": {
    "friend": [
      {
        "email": "aa@aa.aa",
        "firstName": "aa",
        "id": "31",
        "lastName": "aa"
      },
      {
        "email": "bb@bb.bb",
        "firstName": "bb",
        "id": "32",
        "lastName": "bb"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem is (I googled a lot, and the best article is - [Java & Json: Wrapping elements when serialising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567395/java-json-wrapping-elements-when-serialising)) but in the example - I got only one row in the lower level and if I'm using something like this:

```
    public class JsonSimpleExample {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         org.json.simple.JSONObject jsonObject3=new org.json.simple.JSONObject();
         org.json.simple.JSONObject jsonObject2=new org.json.simple.JSONObject();
         for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
         org.json.simple.JSONObject jsonObject=new org.json.simple.JSONObject();

         Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            data.put("email","aa@aa.aa");
            data.put("firstName","aa");
            data.put("lastName","aa");
            data.put("id",j);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.putAll( data );
         jsonObject2.put("friend",json); 
         jsonObject3.put("friends",jsonObject2); 
    }

    System.out.print(jsonObject3);

}
```

Here I got only the last row, what is obvious. For the other hand - while I'm using HashMap or Map - I got a little bit different format. May be I should use something from this example (I mean List), but not sure how it finally should be: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743227/creating-parent-property-in-json](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/).
So, I implemented it this way:

```
public class JsonSimpleExample {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         org.json.simple.JSONObject jsonObject3=new org.json.simple.JSONObject();
         org.json.simple.JSONObject jsonObject2=new org.json.simple.JSONObject();

         JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
         HashMap<String, JSONObject> map = new HashMap<String, JSONObject>();
            for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
                JSONObject data=new JSONObject();
                data.put("email","aa@aa.aa"+i);
                data.put("firstName","aa");
                data.put("lastName","aa");
                data.put("id",i);
                map.put("json" + i, data);
                arr.put(map.get("json" + i));
              }

         jsonObject2.put("friend",arr); 
         jsonObject3.put("friends",jsonObject2); 

        System.out.print(jsonObject3);
    }
    }
```

I don't care for right now about how to generate JSON (I mean - using Jackson, Pojo or something else), my main problem is to understand - if I'm on the right way on getting the same data format as I had after XML to JSON data conversion. And what could I improve in my code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serializing and Deserializing JSON objects are quite easy when you use some existing libraries (why to re-invent wheel?). What you could improve is to use gson - Google's library for working with json. I will explain how it works:-

Create a Friend Class with all the fields you require.

```
Class Friend{
  String email;
  String firstName;
  Integer id;
  String lastName;

  Friend(String email,String firstName,Integer id,String lastName){
    this.email = email;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.id = id;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  //This is Constructor
  }
}
```

Create a class for you enclosing JSON Object friends:

```
Class Friends{
  Friend[] friend;

  Friends(Friend[] friend){
     this.friend = friend;
  }
}
```

Now say `obj` is of type Friends. You will simple get the JSON string by:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonInString = gson.toJson(obj);
```

References:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Let me know if you still have trouble making it work!

Comment: Mangat, I implemented 2 separate classes as you described. But the problem is - I got code: `import com.google.gson.*;

public class Gson {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
       Friend friend = new Friend();
       friend.setEmail("email");
       friend.setFirstName("first");
       friend.setLastName("last");
       friend.setId(2);

       Gson gson = new Gson();
       String json = gson.toJson(friend);
 }
}` but I got an error here: at *toJson* I got an error - The method toJson(Friend) is undefined for the type Gson. I'm using gson-2.6.2.jar library. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to create the Gson jar. Its already imported by import com.google.gson.Gson; When you created Gson class, it has masked the original Gson class from google

Comment: Oh, I got it (I made it by mistake, just decided that this gonna be a good name for my class).. Thank you, Mangat

Comment: Just one last thing - how could I add top level "Friend" tag in this code: `public class jsonnew {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Friends friends = new Friends(null);
 List<Friend> friends = new ArrayList<Friend>(); 
  
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  Friend friend = new Friend();
     friend.setEmail("email");
     friend.setFirstName("first");
     friend.setLastName("last");
     friend.setId(i); 
     friends.add(friend);
 } 
    
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(friends);
    System.out.println(json);
    }
}` Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a Friend class which has fields for email, id, firstName, lastName, etc.
Populate a collection object with Friend class instances.
Serialize the collection.